# unable to upgrade to lts (or any supported distro) I am new no dvd

Tags: boot, upgrade, usb, dvd

I bought a cheap laptop off gumtree. Unfortunately it does not come with dvd so I cannot install 15.1 or 14.04 on it. I do have old linux 11.2 I think but there is no way that I can see to upgrade it to work. I even bought external dvd but bios on this machine is so ascent that you cannot boot from external dvd or usb... i tried to update bios no files available. computer manufacturer went bust 6 years ago.
im new to ubuntu help pls

Comment: Which manufacturer and model is the laptop, and have you tried a bootable USB?

Comment: Iqon 8050q I think and yes , but that wont work as after you reset the laptop you can only choose : floppy (that this laptop dont have.. lan , hdd and cd- linux 14.4 wont fit on cd right?)

Comment: Even though it says CD, the DVD should work depending on the disk driver. If not, you can use a [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Comment: Sorry just realised you posted hyperlink. Let me give it a go tomorrow, which one is better kde or,gnome then if I have to chose one myself

Comment: when iv tried minimal cd.. laptop beeped then shown me an options and whichever i choose all that happens is that on the top of the screen with black squares (still the same loading menu just with black squares and nothing happens... please see link [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img633/6026/syMtlE.jpg)

Comment: I managed to install 14.10 but I had to install using force pae I have not idea what pae is and what's more now I have to install kernel myself... And of,course I have no idea how

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/WithFloppies) might be of some help to you if you have a floppy drive.

Comment: it would if I had floppy... if I burn that on cd would that help? besically I have to roms: Laptop has built in cdrom (it claims to be dvd but i TRIED both formats and it did not boot) and I have external liteon dvd rewriter with every possible dvd read mode. would that help? also is there a way to upgrade it without booting him up again? i see there was posibility of upgrading to 11.4 but thats gone now (404 unable to find page)/ check your internet connection, each time i try.

Comment: I see no reason why a live CD wouldn't work either. That should be worth a shot.

Comment: Just to clarify (I did say I am a newbie :), by live cd are you referring to minimal install or to those files in this article or is there live cd somewhere with version 14.01?

Comment: I am pretty new to linux as well. I would recommend looking at software that would allow you to mount the Ubuntu 14.0x on CDs.

Comment: any idea which?

Comment: In the column on the left in [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-ubuntu-10-04-on-flash-drive-using-windows/) page there is a link for "Creating an Ubuntu Live USB from CD". I would give that a shot if I were you. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: Usb wont work as i cannot select,this option on my laptop and file size wont fit onto cd..